# using accented letters in jasper report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm having trouble with accented letters using jasper report, the encode of the report is Cp1252 and i use a JavaBean to fill it

When i print it the letters is ok, but if I export it to pdf the letters with accents are replaced with a blank space.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you use the [Font Extensions](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/index.html#fontextensions) mechanism?